# Minimizer of a convex function.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I found this result on some lectures about optimization:
.

*Let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable convex function. Then $x$ is a minimizer* of $f$ if and only if

$$\langle x'-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle \ge 0 \qquad \forall x'$$

Shouldn't be $\langle x'-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle = 0 \quad \forall x'$, if $x$ is a minimizer of $f$?

Comment: If $x^*$ is a minimizer, isn’t then true that $\nabla f (x^*) = 0$ and hence that the scalar product above is zero?

Comment: Is $x \mapsto x^2$ on $[1, 2]$ allowed (the minimum is $x=1$)?

Comment: Ok basically the condition $\nabla f (x^*) = 0$ holds only when $x^*$is the global minimum point.. but is this true only for convex functions?

Comment: What if $x^\ast$ is a boundary point, as in my example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that $\ X\ $ is an open convex subset of some finite dimensional Euclidean space $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $ (although the result will also hold in more general cases too).

If $\ \left\langle x^\prime -x, \nabla f(x)\right\rangle\ge0\ $ for *all* $\ x^\prime\ $, then we get $\ \left\langle y, \nabla f(x)\right\rangle\ge0\ $ for *any* $\ y\ $ by taking $\ x^\prime=y-x\ $, and $\ \left\langle y, \nabla f(x)\right\rangle\le0\ $ by taking $\ x^\prime=-y-x\ $. Hence, the condition $\ \left\langle x^\prime -x, \nabla f(x)\right\rangle\ge0\ $ for all $\ x^\prime\ $ is equivalent to the condition $\ \left\langle y, \nabla f(x)\right\rangle=0\ $ for all $\ y\ $, or, equivalently, $\ \nabla f(x)=0\ $.  For a differentiable convex function, this is a necessary and sufficient for $\ x\ $ to be a minimiser of $\ f\ $.

Answer (score 0):

> *Let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable convex function. Then $x$ is a minimizer* of $f$ if and only if
>
> $$\langle x'-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle \ge 0 \qquad \forall x'$$

Note that this result holds for a **general convex set** $X$. A proof can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3930872/31498).

> Shouldn't be $\langle x'-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle = 0 \quad \forall x'$,
> if $x$ is a minimizer of $f$?

You were probably thinking about the common optimality condition for **unconstrained** problem (e.g. when $X=\mathbb{R}^n$), in which case $\nabla f(x) = 0$. It turns out that this result even holds for a general **open** convex set $X$.

Indeed, if $X$ is open, then for $\epsilon > 0$ small enough, both $x+\epsilon\nabla f(x)$ and $x-\epsilon\nabla f(x)$ belongs to $X$. Replacing $x'$ in $\langle x'-x,\nabla f(x)\rangle \ge 0$ with these two vectors in turn, we obtain $\epsilon \nabla f(x) \ge 0 \ge \epsilon \nabla f(x)$, which means $\nabla f(x) = 0$.